# Java: Strange multi-threaded login check/sequence

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sockets

I found this login sequence/client check from an unkown multi-threaded server written in Java, but I fail to understand what and why this check is being done after the client socket has been accapted with the server socket:

```
public static int MaxConnections = 100000;

public static int[] ConnectionCount = new int[MaxConnections];

int Found = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < MaxConnections; i++)    {
    if (Connections[i] == connectedClientID)    {
        Found = ConnectionCount[i];
        break;
    }
}

if (Found < 3)  {
    System.out.println("Connection accepted from " + connectedClientID + ": " + socket.getPort() + ".");
    connectionHandler.newConnectingClient(socket, connectedClientID);
} else {
    System.out.println("Server: Rejected " + connectedClientID + ":" + socket.getPort());
    socket.close();
}
```

Thanks for any explanation/hint.

Comment: The server apparently only allows 3 connections per client IP address. Unfortunately, there is no way in Java to reject a TCP connection before accepting it. So, the connection is closed right after accepting it.

Comment: What @nosid said.  That would immunize the server against a DOS attack from a single host.

Comment: Or, given the quality of the code, it would try to do that.

Comment: But if the three first connections to the server is made, how can anyone else connect to the server later, when the third slot is occupied? Does not this check limit the maximum of possible connections at all by three?

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen `Found` is not set to the index `i` but to the value in the `ConnectionCount` array at the index `i`. How this value in the `ConnectionCount` array is set or updated is not shown in the code you posted.

Comment: @vanOekel, it seems that the array ConnectionCount is only assosiated in the loop.